# Using SQL Server Arithmetic Operators on varchar Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting, arithmetic-expressions

I have a third party data source that has a `varchar(255)` column that contains only numbers. This column is the cost of an item. I would like to be able to multiply this column by a factor (2.3) to get a default selling price but I cannot apply arithmetic operators on the `varchar` column and the `CAST` function is producing an error when combined with the arithmetic operators.

This statement produces the following sample results:

```
SELECT 
    AverageCost
FROM 
    dbo.inventory
```

- 169
- 32.5
- 55.25
- 8.42
- 295
- 0
- 3.33333

This satatement:

```
SELECT 
    AverageCost * 2.3 AS Price
FROM 
    dbo.iteminventory
```

Produces this error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting data type numeric

Writing the statement as follows to cast as a decimal produces no errors but adding the arithmetic operator into this statement has eluded me, my attempts have all resulted in errors.

```
SELECT 
    CAST(AverageCost AS Decimal(10, 2)) AS Price
FROM 
    dbo.inventory
```

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 2012+ use **Try_Convert()**

Try_Convert() will catch any conversion errors as a NULL

```
SELECT try_convert(float,AverageCost) * 2.3 AS Price 
FROM   dbo.inventory
```

**Returns**

```
Price
388.7
74.75
127.075
19.366
678.5
0
7.666659
```

To see the values which may be causing the conversion error

```
Select *
 From  iteminventory
 Where try_convert(float,AverageCost) is null
```

Comment: @B.L. Happy to help